# How to implement Cloudways CDN on Magento2

Tags: magento2, cdn

I have a website which is hosted on Amazon **AWS EC2** and Domain is on **123-reg**, I have pointed domain via AMAZON Elastic IP, Please see attached image, Now i want to setup CDN only for static files.
How to do that? Do I need to point whole DNS on cloudways?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can configure separate domain for static content

Login to Magento Admin and 
set "Base URL for Static View Files" and/or "Secure Base URL for Static View Files" in Stores > Configuration > Base URLs to the desired CDN domain, e.g. https://cdn.domain.com/static/

For base host configure CORS policy to allow access to cdn.domain.com from original domain

For example in Apache

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>        
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://cdn.domain.com"
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range"

</IfModule>
```

or for NGINX

```
location / {

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://cdn.domain.com';

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';

...
```

See more details here https://sherocommerce.com/setting-amazon-aws-cloudfront-cdn-magento-2/